# Linked list has different behaviour for similar pointer assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am writing a code to delete a node from a linked list when only the pointer to the node is given and the head node is not given

```
/*
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
  Node(int x) {
    data = x;
    next = NULL;
  }
}*head;
*/

// This function should delete node from linked list. The function
// may assume that node exists in linked list and is not last node
// node: reference to the node which is to be deleted
void deleteNode(Node *node)
{
        node=(node->next);
}
```

does not delete the present pointer in the list, but,

```
/*
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
  Node(int x) {
    data = x;
    next = NULL;
  }
}*head;
*/

// This function should delete node from linked list. The function
// may assume that node exists in linked list and is not last node
// node: reference to the node which is to be deleted
void deleteNode(Node *node)
{
        *node=*(node->next);
}
```

Deletes the node from the linked list

Why? what is the difference between the approach?

Comment: Both leak memory.  The first one leaks the next node.  The second overwrites the current node with the values from the next node, then leaks the now former next node.

Comment: A complete explanation here requires a thorough understanding of what pointers are, and how they work. Unfortunately, this is a fairly long topic, and stackoverflow isn't really a replacement for a good C++ book; so you'll just have to spend some quality time with yours', on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's take a simpler example with integers instead of nodes:

```
void Modify_1 (int *piVal, int *piNewVal)
 {  
    //piVal has adresse of i passed as argument 

     // similar to  node = (node->next);    
     piVal = piNewVal;  // This change just the VALUE of the pointer passed as argument !  


    //piVal has adresse of j now
 }

void Modify_2 (int *piVal)
{
    // similar to *node=*(node->next);
    *piVal = 0; // This change de content of pointer 
}

int main ()
{
    int i = 3;
    int j = 5;

    Modify_1 (&i, &j);
    cout << i << endl; // This print 3 !

    Modify_2 (&i);
    cout << i << endl; // This print 0

    return 0;
}
```

`piVal` is a `pointer` that contains `i` address VALUE. Exemple : `0x00bcfdb4`
This address is passed as a value (0x00bcfdb4) if you want to function.
As long as you do not write `*piVal`, you are not going to change the pointed content but just the VALUE of the address.

If you want to change the pointer, you need an `**int` (in your case `**node`)

```
void Modify_3 (int **piVal, int *piNewVal)
{
   *piVal = piNewVal;   // this change de pointer adresse
}  

int main ()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *pi = &x;
    Modify_3 (&pi, &x);

    cout << *pi << endl; // This print 5  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to a (non-reference) argument of a function has no effect outside that function.
(The most important thing to learn about pointers is that there is nothing special about pointers.)

It's the same as how

```
void f(int x) { x = 1000; }

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    f(x);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

will print `0`, not `1000`.

Thus, your first attempt does not modify anything and has no observable effect.

Your second attempt also has a problem - it copies the next node but doesn't delete it.
If your nodes are dynamically alloacted, and they usually are, this is a memory leak.

You need something like this:

```
void deleteNode(Node *node)
{
    Node* old = node->next;
    *node = *(node->next);
    delete old;
}
```

It's a bit unconventional to modify a list by copying nodes, though, since it is very inefficent if the node's data is big.
Usually, you update the links in the list, but in order to do that you need to know what the previous node is.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a node from a linked list when only the pointer to the node is given - that's possible only in doubly linked list or in indexed list. The nature of list itself  says that you have to modify another node to remove one from existing chain.

In first case node contains pointer to previous node and cost is O(1), while with indexed list you have index (key) and access to mapping\indexing mechanism, cost of getting previous node depends on method used. For the last reason indexed lists are sometimes implemented as doubly-linked.